# How can I remove a Host entry from an ssh config file?

Tags: ssh, sed

The standard format of the file is:

```
Host example
  HostName example.com
  Port 2222
Host example2
  Hostname two.example.com

Host three.example.com
  Port 4444
```

Knowing the host's short name, I want to remove an entire entry in order to re-add it with new details.

The closest I have got is this, except I need to keep the following Host declaration and the second search term will capture two many terms (like `HostName`):

```
sed '/Host example/,/\nHost/d'
```

Comment: In the general case, you need a parser for this file format. There is no guarantee that entries will be indented, or that indented lines are part of a preceding entry, let alone that the next top-level directive will be a `Host` directive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GNU sed:

```
host="example"
sed 's/^Host/\n&/' file | sed '/^Host '"$host"'$/,/^$/d;/^$/d'
```

Output:

```
Host example2
  Hostname two.example.com
Host three.example.com
  Port 4444
```

---

> `s/^Host/\n&/`: Insert a newline before every line that begins with "Host"
>
> `/^Host '"$host"'$/,/^$/d`: delete all lines matching "Host $host" to next empty line
>
> `/^$/d`: clean up: delete every empty line

Answer (score 2):

My final solution (which is somewhat OSX orientated) was this. It's largely based on Cyrus' earlier answer.

```
sed < $SOURCE "/^$/d;s/Host /$NL&/" | sed '/^Host '"$HOST"'$/,/^$/d;' > $SOURCE
```

This is more resilient to `HostName` directives which aren't indented.