# Bash extract user for a particular host from ssh config file

Tags: bash, ssh, sed

I'm writing a bash script where I need to obtain a particular user from an ssh config file. The ssh config file looks a little something like this:

```
HOST blag
    HostName blag.net.au
    Port 2683
    User blaguser
Host bloo
  User ABCDEF
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
HOST biff
    HostName biff.net.au
    Port 2683
    User biffuser
```

I want to obtain the string 'ABCDEF' and put it in a variable, by searching for Host bloo.

I was able to use the answer at https://superuser.com/questions/791374/get-variable-values-from-config-file/791387#791387?newreg=6626dd5535194d0180a91b6ace31e16f to read the config file but it assigns the array with the last host entry in the file.

I'm able to delete the host entry with this answer [How can I remove a Host entry from an ssh config file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110829/how-can-i-remove-a-host-entry-from-an-ssh-config-file). The sed command here could be edited to extract the correct `User` but I'm not sure precisely how

I'm having a lot of trouble with it. Can anyone assist? An answer which uses sed would be preferable.

Comment: `var=$(awk '/^Host bloo$/{x=1}x&&/User/{print $2;exit}' ssh.conf)`

Comment: @123 Noice. Works perfect, if you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Note that `openssh` config is not case sensitive, which might get you fooled. Using `ssh` itself will shield you from these details. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `ssh` configuration test mode to parse the configuration file and return you the expected value:

```
ssh -G hostname | grep "^user "
```

This should work since `openssh-6.8`.

Comment: I have version 6.6.1 sadly.

Comment: 2 years later, found my own question again but this time running OpenSSH 7.4 so this answer is better. Just be careful about checking for a hostname that doesn't exist in the config. It'll return whatever user you run the command as. That's pretty easy to check for but you might be expecting nothing.

Comment: If you have a `Host *` with a `User` set it will always be that one no matter what.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @Jakuje's correct answer. This one will return only the username

```
$ ssh -G hostname | grep -m1 -oP "(?<=user ).*"
ubuntu
```

where grep parameters mean

`-m1` - stop reading after first matches

`-o`  - print only the matching part of the line

`-P`  - use Perl compatible positive look behind regex

Comment: Not really of concern here, but I guess this regex will be quite slow. You can make it a lot easier with cut: `ssh -G hostname | grep "^user " | head -1 | cut -d " " -f2-`

Answer (score 3):

As per 123's comment above:

```
var=$(awk '/^Host bloo$/{x=1}x&&/User/{print $2;exit}' ssh.conf)
```

That will assign value `ABCDEF` to var.