# Grab an IdentityFile from an ssh config based on a variable hostname via shell script

Tags: shell, parsing, awk, ssh, ssh-config

I'm writing a shell script where I need to obtain an `IdentityFile` from an ssh config file. The ssh config file looks like this:

```
​Host AAAA
    User aaaa
    IdentityFile /home/aaaa/.ssh/aaaaFILE
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubkeyAuthentication=yes
    PreferredAuthentications=publickey
​Host BBBB
    User bbbb
    IdentityFile /home/aaaa/.ssh/bbbbFILE
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubkeyAuthentication=yes
    PreferredAuthentications=publickey
​Host CCCC
    User cccc
    IdentityFile /home/aaaa/.ssh/ccccFILE
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    PubkeyAuthentication=yes
    PreferredAuthentications=publickey
```

I want to obtain the string following `IdentityFile` based on a given `Hostname` and put it in a variable. The hostname will be provided by a shell variable called `${HOSTNAME}`.

I was able to use the answer at [Bash extract user for a particular host from ssh config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304271/bash-extract-user-for-a-particular-host-from-ssh-config-file) to read the config file and grep for a single specific `IdentityFile` based on a single specific `Hostname`, but I can't get the hang of passing a variable into awk.

So far I've tried

```
SSH_CONFIG="/home/aaaa/.ssh/config"
# Note AAAA is the hostname for this case
KEY=$(awk '/^Host AAAA$/{x=1}x&&/IdentityFile/{print $2;exit}' ${SSH_CONFIG})
echo "${KEY}" 

OUTPUT: "/home/aaaa/.ssh/aaaaFILE"
```

which works because I'm giving the exact hostname to parse.
But using

```
SSH_CONFIG="/home/aaaa/.ssh/config"
HOSTNAME=AAAA
KEY=$(awk -vcon="${HOSTNAME}" '/^Host con$/{x=1}x&&/IdentityFile/{print $2;exit}' ${SSH_CONFIG})
echo "${KEY}" 

OUTPUT: ""
```

does not work. I know for a fact `${HOSTNAME}` is being set because I am setting myself (and echoing it). I would like to pass a variable because I do not want the hostname hardcoded and will not know what the value is until the script is called.

**I am also stuck using and older version of ssh (OpenSSH_6.6.1) which does not have the convenient `ssh -G HOSTNAME` option.**

What am I missing when it comes to awk variables? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU grep and Perl Compatible Regular Expressions:

```
hostname="AAAA"
grep -Poz "Host $hostname(.*\n)*?.*IdentityFile \K.*" ~aaaa/.ssh/config
```

Output:

```
/home/aaaa/.ssh/aaaaFILE
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @Cyrus. This worked for me. I'm choosing your answer because `grep` allows for more brevity.

Answer (score 5):

I appreciate the scripting attempts, but OpenSSH client already knows how to parse the configuration:

```
ssh -G $hosname | grep identityfile | awk '{print $2}' | head -n 1
```

note, that it will also list the default identities, but with `IdentitiesOnly=yes` it should list the one from configuration as the first one.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I am also stuck using and older version of ssh (OpenSSH_6.6.1) which does not have the convenient ssh -G HOSTNAME option. Unless you would like to roll a Debian package for me, I am stuck scripting sans `ssh -G`.

Comment: @Wimateeka sorry, I missed that part. Maybe time to update?

Comment: That's unfortunately not my decision to make, but trust me, I'd love to update. I've already been dinged with not having a verbose option for sshpass because of this too.

Answer (score 1):

mmm for some reason, the example you posted has strange non-printable characters before **Host** word. This regular expression only matched the first line: `/^Host/`, while it should match 3 total lines.

I fixed that by deleting those characters and saving it again.

So, answering your question, you can't use variables inside a regular expression in awk.

But this also works and do the same:

```
HOSTNAME="BBBB"
awk -v host=$HOSTNAME '/Host/ && $2==host {found=1} /IdentityFile/ && found {print $2; exit}' ${SSH_CONFIG}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion @valrog. This worked for me.